# Swiftmailer is using the same file for multiple attachments

Tags: yii, swiftmailer

I'm using the yii-mail module for Yii, which is based on the Swiftmailer. I was trying to send mutiple attachments in one email and it doesn't seem to work right.

Here's the code

```
 $agbpath        = 'path\\to\\file.pdf';
 $agb1path       = 'path\\to\\anotherfile.pdf';

 $message        = new YiiMailMessage;

 $message->setSubject('TEST')
 ->setFrom(array('someone@test.com' => 'Someone'))
 ->setTo(array('recipient@test.com'))
 ->setBcc(array('copy@test.com'))
 ->setBody('LoremIpsum', 'text/html')
 ;
 $message->attach(Swift_Attachment::fromPath("$agb1path"));

 $message->attach(Swift_Attachment::fromPath("$agbpath"));

 Yii::app()->mail->send($message);
```

Both files exist but every time both attachments contain the same file although with different filenames. I tried changing the order and this only changes which file is being sent in both attachments.

The whole thing is running on Zend Server on Windows Server 2008 R2.

As you see I even tried using just hardcoded values, so that errors from the form wouldn't have any influence on the email itself.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2):

It's a problem on Windows os.
The fix for that is to disable the cache before attach the files.

```
Swift_Preferences::getInstance()->setCacheType('null');
```

Comment: Confirmet this too for Symfony 2.7.6

Answer (score 0):

More likely you have to call the attach this way:

```
$message->attach($agb1path);
```

if you're on Yii2 the attach method already calls [`Swift_Attachment::fromPath`](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer/blob/master/Message.php#L242). I believe the same works even for Yii1